# TYPO3 Form Finisher: form_serialnumber and savetodatabase

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x, typo3-form

I'm using @armin 's form_serialnumber extension.
It works fine: I can receive the serial number in the email sent by the EmailToSender finisher.
I can't find how to register the serial field with the SaveToDatabase finisher. Any suggestions?
I have tried various methods including:

```
    Serialnumber.serialnumber:
      mapOnDatabaseColumn: serial
```

or

```
    serialnumber:
      mapOnDatabaseColumn: serial
```

Thank you
Roberto